# what's are best materials for a beginner to learn about OS-level concurrency

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, locks

What are good introductory tutorial /online course /books /approaches to learn the following topics:

- process, threads
- common concurrency issues
- locks, mutexes, semaphores
- context switching
- deadlock and how to avoid
- livelock and how to avoid
- scheduling
- multi-core technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a strong and solid understanding of concurrency I will advise you to read [The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123973376). It became classic reading so far.